# How can I create a laser beam effect with additive blending..?

Tags: three.js

I would like to create a laser beam effect as described here: http://codepoke.net/2011/12/27/opengl-libgdx-laser-fx/

But when I set blending to THREE.AdditiveBlending the color of the laser beam gets blended with the background color. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIG0e.png ( 3rd pic on the right ).

I don't know if its related to the wrong blending or if something is wrong with the color mixing in my shader, however I suspect it has to do something with blending.

My shader code are just a few lines, I use the same texture as in the blog entry.

```
uniform sampler2D uTex;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
vec4 texelColor = texture2D( uTex, vUv );
vec4 color = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color.rgb,texelColor.rgb,texelColor.a),texelColor.a);
```

How can I achieve the cool looks like in the video so that the laser color stays red if it's red but still use additive blending to make it look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is right already. Change the grass background with a background like in the example you're using as reference and you should get similar results.